# how to count weekly additions of lines using github api?

Tags: github, github-api

Reference: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-number-of-additions-and-deletions-per-week

I tried :https://api.github.com/repos/Md-Mudassir/cruiser/stats/code_frequency

```
Response:
[
  [
    1571529600,
    59258,
    -59151
  ],
  [
    1572134400,
    30660,
    -18359
  ],
  [
    1572739200,
    1688,
    -1731
  ],
  [
    1573344000,
    9087,
    -9371
  ],
  [
    1573948800,
    0,
    0
  ]
]
```

But I don't understand the response, how do I convert it so that it's readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is composed of:

- a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which refers to the start of the week for the next two numbers
- the number of lines added
- the number of lines removed.

You must [convert the Epoch number](https://www.epochconverter.com/) in order to derive the week.

Comment: I converted 1688  -> 28 minutes and 8 seconds.
does that mean its addition of 28 lines?

Comment: @MohammedMudassir only the first number is a time. The other are line numbers (added/removed)